# java File not Found return Message

Tags: java

I check the CSV file in a folder and did some of the conditions. now my problem is, If a CSV file not inside the folder i want to return file not found message  for one time.  i write like this `System.out.println("CSV File Not Found");` it will return message for every time when it check a csv file inside the folder..

```
public static void csv_Checking() throws Exception
  {
  File folder = new File(filepath);
  File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
  Date date = new Date();
  SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMddyy");
        String today_date = dateFormat.format(date);
        for(File file : listOfFiles) {
            if(file.isFile()) {
                String CSVFile = file.getName();
                String logName_Error = CSVFile.substring(0, 5);
                String logName_Success = CSVFile.substring(0, 7);
                if(logName_Error.equals("error")) {
                    String Month = CSVFile.substring(5, 11);
                    if(Month.equals(today_date)) {
                        String fName = file.getName();
                        File fileName = new File(filepath + fName);
                        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
            LineNumberReader lineReader = new LineNumberReader(fileReader);
                        int lineNumber = 0;
                        while(lineReader.readLine() != null) {
                            lineNumber++;
                        }
                        lineReader.close();
                        if(fileName.length() == 0) {
                            String errorMessage = err_messg1;
                            mailMethod(errorMessage);
                        } else if(fileName.length() > 1) {
            String errorMessage = err_messg2 + fileName.length() +err_messg2_1;
                            mailMethod(errorMessage);
                        } else if(lineNumber > 1) {
                            String errorMessage = err_messg3;
                            mailMethod(errorMessage);
                        }
                    } 
                } else if(logName_Success.equals("success")) {
                    String Month = CSVFile.substring(7, 13);
                    if(Month.equals(today_date))
                    {
                        String fName = file.getName();
                        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
            LineNumberReader lineReader = new LineNumberReader(fileReader);
                        File fileName = new File(filepat

    h + fName);
                            int lineNumber = 0;
                        while(lineReader.readLine() != null){
                            lineNumber++;
                        }
                        lineReader.close();
                        if(fileName.length() == 0) {
                            String errorMessage = err_messg1;
                            mailMethod(errorMessage);
                        } else if(fileName.length() > 1) {
                            String errorMessage = err_messg2 + fileName.length() +err_messg2_1;
                            mailMethod(errorMessage);
                        } else if(lineNumber > 1) {
                            String errorMessage = err_messg3;
                            mailMethod(errorMessage);
                        }
                    } else if(!Month.equals(today_date)){
  System.out.println("This file Was not Match with Today's Date - " + CSVFile +"\n");
                    }
                } 
            }
            System.out.println("CSV File Not Found");
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Please be clearer about what it does and what you are expecting it to do.

Comment: Throw a FileNotFoundException ?

Comment: To get the most out of the site it is important to [ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), that includes creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: Did I get it wrong or is this a simple straight forward programming task?

Answer (score 0):

You should surround your code with a try/catch block.

```
try {
    // your code for reading ...

} catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
    System.out.println("CSV File Not Found ...\n" + fnfe.getMessage());
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    System.out.println("Another IO Exception ...\n" + ioe.getMessage());
}
```